# Three players toss an unfair coin - Give an intuitive explanation of dependent

Tags: probability, independence

Three players toss an unfair coin each, independently of each other, with the same probability p = 1/3 that the coin shows heads.

Let X = 1 if player #2 gets the same result as player #1 - Call this a success (otherwise X = 0).

Let Y = 1 if player #3 gets the same result as player #1 - Call this a success (otherwise Y = 0).

From calculations, I know that X and Y are dependent - And is easy to show.

But I find it difficult to give an intuitive explanation of why X and Y are dependent. Can someone help with an intuitive explanation for this.

Comment: if $X=1$ then it is most likely that player 1 tossed tales, which make it more likely that $Y=1$

Comment: Intuitively, both $X$ and $Y$ are dependent on what player $1$ tossed, and so they’re likely to be dependent on each other.

Comment: @mjqxxxx also the coins are biased towards tails.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Right ... if player $1$'s coin were fair, for instance, then $X$ and $Y$ would both be *independent* of what player $1$ tossed, and so they'd likely be independent of each other.

Answer (score 1):

The dependence of $X$ and $Y$ is intimately related to the value of $p$, since if the coin is fair, $X$ and $Y$ are actually *independent*.  To understand why, let the outcomes of each player's coin toss be denoted $T_1, T_2, T_3$ where $\Pr[T_i = 1] = p$.  We can calculate
$$\begin{align}
\Pr[Y = 1 \mid X = 1] &= \Pr[T_3 = T_1 \mid T_2 = T_1] \\
&= \frac{\Pr[T_3 = T_2 = T_1]}{\Pr[T_2 = T_1]} \\
&= \frac{p^3 + (1-p)^3}{p^2 + (1-p)^2},
\end{align}$$
and
$$\Pr[Y = 1] = \Pr[T_3 = T_1] = p^2 + (1-p)^2.$$  Thus if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, we require $p \in \{0, 1/2, 1\}$, of which only $p = 1/2$ admits a non-deterministic sample space.  An intuitive way to see this is to note that if the coin is fair, then the event $T_1 = T_2 = 1$ has the same probability as $T_1 = T_2 = 0$.  The same is true for $T_1$ and $T_3$.  So whether the first two players' coin tosses match does not provide any information about whether the outcome of those coins were more likely to have shown two heads, or if they were more likely to have shown two tails.  This is no longer true if $p \ne 1/2$.

Indeed, in such a case, the event $T_1 = T_2$ is *partially informative* of the outcome of both coin tosses; hence will *increase* the conditional probability of seeing a match between the third and first tosses.

Comment: Thanks. Let's say that p=1/3, then Pr[Y=1∣X=1]=3/5, and Pr[Y=1]=5/9. It makes good sense in the calculations, but how can you give an intuitive explanation of how the extra 2/45 appears given that we know that X=1. 

Is it possible to draw a diagram or similar to realize the intuition. I'm struggling a bit with that.